# Jenkins SSH Pipeline Steps -- com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@84d6b5c

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to execute ssh commands in a remote machine.

I am running jenkins as a service on Ubuntu

Steps Followed

1 -- Installed ssh-steps-plugin

2 -- On my jenkins master i have generated the ssh keys from jenkins user and copied the public key to the remote host and i am able to login to the remote host using this key

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  574 Jul 22 18:12 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 2610 Jul 22 18:12 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  222 Jul 22 18:14 known_hosts
jenkins@mydevmachine:~/.ssh$
jenkins@mydevmachine:~/.ssh$
jenkins@mydevmachine:~/.ssh$  ssh -i id_rsa vagrant@192.168.30.2
Last login: Thu Jul 22 19:50:45 2021 from 192.168.30.1
[vagrant@k8s-lb ~]$
```

3 -- Created a Global credentials to hold the username and privatekey

[image]

4 -- Created a simple pipeline using the below Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage("SSH-Test"){
            steps{
                script{
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
                credentialsId: "ssh-k8s-lb", 
                keyFileVariable: 'sshKey',
                usernameVariable: 'sshUser'
            )]) {
                def remote = [:];
                remote.name = 'k8s-lb';
                remote.host = '192.168.30.2';
                remote.user = sshUser; 
                remote.identityFile = sshKey;
                remote.allowAnyHosts = true;
                
                sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -lrt"
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SSHTest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (SSH-Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $sshKey
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sshCommand
Executing command on k8s-lb[192.168.30.2]: ls -lrt sudo: false
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@84d6b5c
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:664)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:561)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:406)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:387)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.UserAuthentication$Trait$Helper.configureUserAuthentication(UserAuthentication.groovy:36)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.UserAuthentication$Trait$Helper$configureUserAuthentication$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.configureUserAuthentication(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.UserAuthentication$configureUserAuthentication$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy:85)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility.retry(Utility.groovy:52)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility$retry.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:83)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connect(ConnectionManager.groovy:59)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$connect.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.wetRun(SessionTask.groovy:61)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.call(SessionTask.groovy:48)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service.run(Service.groovy:81)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.SSHService.executeCommand(SSHService.groovy:177)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution$CommandCallable.execute(CommandStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.call(SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.java:32)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:46)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution.run(CommandStep.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SSHStepExecution.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with the ssk-key generation

generated the keys with below

ssh-keygen -m PEM

Comment: Thanks so much for coming back to put the answer, even if it was your own question - this was exactly the same problem I was having.